# Good patterns for a C/C++ plugin-based system?

Tags: c++, c, plugins

When developing a C/C++ (=2?) plugin based framework with shared objects/dynamic libraries that need to support live swapping what examples would be helpful to look at for implementation details?

Thanks.

**Note:** live swapping is the key point here, no need to restart the system is a requirement

Comment: Can you elaborate on operating system?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384121/creating-a-module-system-dynamic-loading-in-c as a starting point.

Comment: Has to support windows and unix

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are on POSIX, `dlopen()`, `dlsym()` and `dlclose()` are all you need.

See `man dlsym` for details and examples.

There is a good [article](http://www.codepedia.com/1/LoadingDynamicLibraryC) about loading dynamic libraries, and plugin infrastructure is an example.

**EDIT** OP added Windows as requirement so this approach won't help since Windows isn't POSIX-compliant. However there are similar functions in WinAPI - see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-porting/index.html).

Comment: Althoug possible I would recommend to use a platform independent library like ACE http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/Current/html/ace/a00110.html

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try [Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.blogspot.com/2007/09/what-is-boostextension.html) but beware : despite its name, it is not one of boost libraries.

Here is a [link to its documentation](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html).

Comment: very niceits not boost(yet) but it's in the sandbox

Answer (score 4):

For C++ plugins you can check [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687) which detail how to achieve it with the previously mentionned posix calls.

Quoting the article :

> Given that we can use these functions to access functions in a C library, how do we use them to access classes in a C++ library? There are several problems to overcome. One is that we must be able to locate the symbols we need in the library. This is trickier than it might seem because of the difference between the way symbols are stored in C and C++ files.

Answer (score 4):

If you want cross-platform library loading without having to develop for each platform's API individually, [libltdl](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html) may help.

> Libtool provides a small library, called `libltdl`, that aims at hiding the various difficulties of dlopening libraries from programmers. It consists of a few headers and small C source files that can be distributed with applications that need dlopening functionality. On some platforms, whose dynamic linkers are too limited for a simple implementation of `libltdl` services, it requires GNU DLD, or it will only emulate dynamic linking with libtool's dlpreopening mechanism.
>
> libltdl supports currently the following dynamic linking mechanisms:
>
> - `dlopen` (Solaris, Linux and various BSD flavors)
> - `shl_load` (HP-UX)
> - `LoadLibrary` (Win16 and Win32)
> - `load_add_on` (BeOS)
> - `NSAddImage` or `NSLinkModule` (Darwin and Mac OS X)
> - GNU DLD (emulates dynamic linking for static libraries)
> - libtool's dlpreopen (see see [Dlpreopening](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Dlpreopening.html#Dlpreopening))

Boost.Extension seems to only support Windows PE `dll`s, UNIX ELF shared objects, and Mac OS X Mach-O bundles.  Well, that may be sufficient for you...

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/boost_extension/shared_libraries/shared_library_class.html) seems nice (never used it but will try soon). Another alternative would be the [POCO SharedLibrary class](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SharedLibrary.html).